# JMS 2.0 - MQ 9 - Topic Shared subscription doesn't work

Tags: java, jms, ibm-mq, subscription, shared

I'm facing problem when developing an application that subscribe a MQ Topic (MQ version 9).

I need to do a shared topic connection because the application will be ran in multiple instances (cluster).

The specs and the documentation says :
"A non-durable shared subscription is used by a client which needs to be able to share the work of receiving messages from a topic subscription amongst multiple consumers. A non-durable shared subscription may therefore have more than one consumer. Each message from the subscription will be delivered to only one of the consumers on that subscription."

For me, all the clients using the same subscription name are in the same "cluster", only one client will receive a message at one time.

In my code, inspired by this [article](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/messaging/entry/shared_subscriptions_sample_using_mq_v8_jms?lang=en), I've got an exception when the second client try to create the shared subscription. I really don't understand if this is a bug in MQ client libraries implementation or in my code.

Here my sample code :

```
    import javax.jms.Connection;
import javax.jms.Message;
import javax.jms.MessageConsumer;
import javax.jms.Session;
import javax.jms.Topic;

import com.ibm.mq.jms.MQTopicConnectionFactory;
import com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.WMQConstants;

public class TestGB2 {

    public static void main(final String[] args) throws Exception {

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            new Thread(new MyThread("THREAD" + i, "TESTSUB/#", "myClient", "SUBTEST")).start();
        }

    }

    public static class MyThread implements Runnable {

        private final String topicString;
        private final String clientId;
        private final String subscriptionName;

        public MyThread(final String threadName, final String topicString, final String clientId, final String subscriptionName) {
            Thread.currentThread().setName(threadName);
            this.topicString = topicString;
            this.clientId = clientId;
            this.subscriptionName = subscriptionName;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {

            try {
                System.out.println(String.format("%s : Connecting...", Thread.currentThread().getName()));
                MQTopicConnectionFactory cf = new MQTopicConnectionFactory();
                cf.setHostName("xxxx");
                cf.setPort(1416);
                cf.setQueueManager("xxxx");
                cf.setTransportType(WMQConstants.WMQ_CM_CLIENT);
                cf.setChannel("xxx");
                cf.setClientID(clientId);

                Connection con = cf.createConnection();

                Session session = con.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
                con.start();
                Topic topic = session.createTopic(topicString);
                MessageConsumer messageConsumer = session.createSharedConsumer(topic, subscriptionName); // fail here

                System.out.println(String.format("%s : Waiting for a message...", Thread.currentThread().getName()));
                Message msg = messageConsumer.receive();
                System.out.println(String.format("%s : Received :\n%s", Thread.currentThread().getName(), msg));

            }
            catch (Exception ex) {
                System.out.println(String.format("%s : FAILED", Thread.currentThread().getName()));
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

    }
}
```

The code below tries to create 10 threads consuming messages on the same topic. Only the first thread is able to connect, all the others fail with following exception :

```
    com.ibm.msg.client.jms.DetailedIllegalStateException: JMSWMQ0026: Failed to subscribe to topic 'TESTSUB' with selector 'none' using MQSUB.
There may have been a problem creating the subscription due to it being used by another message consumer.
Make sure any message consumers using this subscription are closed before trying to create a new subscription under the same name. Please see the linked exception for more information.
    at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.common.internal.Reason.reasonToException(Reason.java:472)
    at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.common.internal.Reason.createException(Reason.java:214)
    at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.internal.WMQMessageConsumer.checkJmqiCallSuccess(WMQMessageConsumer.java:212)
    at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.internal.WMQMessageConsumer.checkJmqiCallSuccess(WMQMessageConsumer.java:112)
    at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.internal.WMQConsumerShadow.initialize(WMQConsumerShadow.java:1038)
    at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.internal.WMQSyncConsumerShadow.initialize(WMQSyncConsumerShadow.java:134)
    at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.internal.WMQMessageConsumer.<init>(WMQMessageConsumer.java:470)
    at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.internal.WMQSession.createSharedConsumer(WMQSession.java:938)
    at com.ibm.msg.client.jms.internal.JmsSessionImpl.createSharedConsumer(JmsSessionImpl.java:4228)
    at com.ibm.msg.client.jms.internal.JmsSessionImpl.createSharedConsumer(JmsSessionImpl.java:4125)
    at com.ibm.mq.jms.MQSession.createSharedConsumer(MQSession.java:1319)
    at TestGB.lambda$0(TestGB.java:33)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: com.ibm.mq.MQException: JMSCMQ0001: WebSphere MQ call failed with compcode '2' ('MQCC_FAILED') reason '2042' ('MQRC_OBJECT_IN_USE').
    at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.common.internal.Reason.createException(Reason.java:202)
    ... 11 more
```

Tried with the last lib :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.ibm.mq</groupId>
    <artifactId>com.ibm.mq.allclient</artifactId>
    <version>9.1.1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks, I've tried the following cases : 1) unique client id for all client + same subscribe name : doesn't work, 2) unique client id + random sub name : works but not as i want (all clients receive the message) 3) random client id + unique  subscribe name ; doesn't work, (all clients receive the message)

Comment: I'll try to find most recent lib

Comment: I've tried with the last com.ibm.mq.allclient lib, still same error :(

Comment: I've changed : see my updated code. I'am using the same client id and the same subscription name so as you said, i'm expecting that the subscription is shared by all the clients but it still doesn't works.

Comment: And now i'm using com.ibm.mq.allclient v 9.1.1.0

Comment: I've updated my code, still the same problem. I think the problem is on the MQ server, I'll open a ticket to IBM

Comment: It's v9, MQ Explorer says : 09010000

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Summary of the issue

The issue is not with your program, the issue is with the model queue associated to the topic you are subscribing to.

On the queue manager if you look at the topic object that your subscription will match, it will have a parameter `MNDURMDL` that points to a model queue.

If you look at the model queue you will note two parameters where either or both can cause the error you are receiving:

```
[ DEFSOPT( EXCL | SHARED ) ]
[ SHARE | NOSHARE ]
```

These must be set to `DEFSOPT(SHARED)` and `SHARE`.  If either one is set to the other value you will only be able to have one subscriber on the shared subscription.

---

### Additional details of the cause of the issue

With IBM MQ Pub/Sub, when you create a JMS subscription MQ treats this as a managed subscription, in the background IBM MQ will create a temporary queue to subscribe to the topic string.  If it is a non-durable subscription the queue is a temporary dynamic queue.

The reason for the failure is that the first thread will open the temporary dynamic queue in an exclusive mode, any other threads then cannot open the temporary dynamic queue and you receive the `MQRC_OBJECT_IN_USE` error.

---

### Possible cause where an application specific `MNDURMDL` model queue was created

I suspect the cause of this is that IBM comes with a few different default model queues.

The default for a non-durable subscriber has these settings:

```
   QUEUE(SYSTEM.NDURABLE.MODEL.QUEUE)      TYPE(QMODEL)
   DEFSOPT(SHARED)                         SHARE
```

There is another default queue that is not pub/sub specific that has these settings:

```
   QUEUE(SYSTEM.DEFAULT.MODEL.QUEUE)       TYPE(QMODEL)
   DEFSOPT(EXCL)                           NOSHARE
```

It is likely that the model queue created for use by your topic object was created with a command like the following that will default to use the setting of the `SYSTEM.DEFAULT.MODEL.QUEUE`.:

```
DEFINE QMODEL(xxx)
```

In the future you could either specifically set those two parameters, or define it with the `LIKE` keyword to force it to use a different queue to model settings from, both commands are below:

```
DEFINE QMODEL(xxx) DEFSOPT(SHARED) SHARE
DEFINE QMODEL(xxx) LIKE(SYSTEM.NDURABLE.MODEL.QUEUE)
```

---

### Additional details on creation and usage of application specific TOPIC objects and MODEL queues

By default the root node of the tree is represented by the standard TOPIC object named `SYSTEM.BASE.TOPIC`, the default model queues associated to this TOPIC are shown below:

```
   TOPIC(SYSTEM.BASE.TOPIC)                TYPE(LOCAL)
   TOPICSTR()                              MDURMDL(SYSTEM.DURABLE.MODEL.QUEUE)
   MNDURMDL(SYSTEM.NDURABLE.MODEL.QUEUE)
```

If you do not define any further administrative TOPIC objects, then all topics match against `SYSTEM.BASE.TOPIC`.  Additionally if you do not define any further administrative TOPIC objects and you want to give an application permission to a specific subset of the topic tree (for example topic strings beginning with `TESTSUB`) you must grant the permissions via `SYSTEM.BASE.TOPIC`, this in turn grants the application access for any arbitrary topic string with no restrictions.

Best practice would be to create a TOPIC object with a topic string that matches the portion of the topic tree an an application should have access to.  Specific to your example of `TESTSUB/#` if your admin defined a new TOPIC object and specified the `TOPICSTR(TESTSUB)`, the defaults would create it like this:

```
   TOPIC(TESTSUB.TOPIC)                    TYPE(LOCAL)
   TOPICSTR(TESTSUB)                       MDURMDL( )
   MNDURMDL( )
```

the blank `MDURMDL` and `MNDURMDL` values tell MQ to use the value from the next closest higher topic object in the tree, if nothing else is defined this would be the `SYSTEM.BASE.TOPIC` and the model queues would still default to using the `SYSTEM.DURABLE.MODEL.QUEUE` and `SYSTEM.NDURABLE.MODEL.QUEUE` model queues.

The admin can instead create the TOPIC object and specify different model queues for example:

```
   TOPIC(TESTSUB.TOPIC)                    TYPE(LOCAL)
   TOPICSTR(TESTSUB)                       MDURMDL(TESTSUB.DURABLE.MODEL.QUEUE)
   MNDURMDL(TESTSUB.NDURABLE.MODEL.QUEUE)
```

By doing this they can define application specific model queues that have the settings required for shared subscriptions and not impact the SYSTEM model queues.  The other benefit is they can provide the application permissions for only topic strings that start with `TESTSUB`, for example `TESTSUB/A` or `TESTSUB/B` or `TESTSUB/X/Y/Z`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I think you're right. I checked the SYSTEM.NDURABLE.MODEL.QUEUE, it's configured as Not Shareable. We recently upgraded the MQ, I think this parameter has changed. I'll check with the administrator

Comment: Note for non-durable subscriptions it is the `SYSTEM.NDURABLE.MODEL.QUEUE`, but also for durable subscriptions it is the `SYSTEM.DURABLE.MODEL.QUEUE` and that should also be set with `DEFSOPT(SHARED) SHARE`.

Comment: I've checked with the administrator, during the upgrade, some default values in the previous version has been lost during the migration. We have added the DEFSOPT(SHARED) and SHARE, it's working like a charm :) Thanks a lot

Comment: My administrator do not want to modify the default value, I'll check a java side solution

Comment: Hi there is no java side solution to this problem if you want to used shared subscriptions. Those are the default values for a brand new queue manager, not sure why they would not want to use them.  I'll update my answer with a few more pointers for possible solutions to your administrator issue.

Comment: @JoshMc In Java, when creating the connection factory, use [cf.setTemporaryModel(XXX)](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSFKSJ_9.1.0/com.ibm.mq.javadoc.doc/WMQJMSClasses/com/ibm/mq/jms/MQConnectionFactory.html#setTemporaryModel-java.lang.String-) to choose a custom model queue `XXX` in case the administrator does not want to modify the default model queue.

Comment: @DanielSteinmann that does not apply to the model queue used for Managed subscriptions, that only applies when the app creates a temporary dynamic queue.

Comment: @DanielSteinmann the model queue used to create the `SYSTEM.MANAGED.[N]DURABLE.*` queues used by JMS subscribers are picked up only from the TOPIC object that the topic string resolves to, the queue created is "managed" by the queue manager.  In fact the application ID that has `sub` authority to the topic string does not even require permission to the model queue specified by the TOPIC object, on the other hand if an application created a temporary queue (TQ) it will require `inq` and either `put` and/or `get` on the model queue depending on if it will be a producer and/or a consumer .

Comment: @JoshMc yes, I was wrong. Thanks for your explanation.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation, I'll try this. For the reason why my admin doesn't want to activate SHARE on the model is that he is afraid of the impact (the whole bank is on MQ) and its argument is that in MQ 9, by default, now it's not shareable (unlike in MQ 8) so he thinks it's for good reason if IBM switch this defaut config

Comment: It is not the default for `SYSTEM.DURABLE.MODEL.QUEUE` and `SYSTEM.NDURABLE.MODEL.QUEUE`.  The default is still `DEFSOPT(SHARED)` and `SHARE`.  Ask them to `crtmqm` a new queue manager and check the default value of those two queues, IBM didn't change those.

Comment: Hi @DanielSteinmann , is it possible to set the model queue not on the connection factory but directly on the MQTopic object ? (like using setProperty), I didn't find anything on the web. Thanks

Comment: It is not possible.   The only place you can set the model queue used by MQ to create dynamic queues for managed subscriptions is on a topic object defined on the queue manager.

Comment: I've tested setTemporaryModel as said @DanielSteinmann but it's does not work : the model is not used when i create the consumer

Comment: Have your MQ Admin create a fresh temp queue manager at MQ v9.1 and look at the `DURABLE` and `NDURABLE` model queues, he or she will see that the IBM default is still `DEFSOPT(SHARED)` and `SHARE`.  The reason you have no control of it from the JMS consumer side is because it is completely configured on the queue manager side, the JMS spec has no concept that a subscription would have a queue behind it, this is just IBM MQ's own back end implementation.

Comment: I've installed by my own an instance of MQ 9.1 (trial version from IBM site), I confirm that you said : by default, all is shared. I see with my MQ Admin why they changed that

Comment: Even better than the trial version is the MQ Advanced for Developers, this one does not expire like the trial.  Check out the [\[ibm-mq\] tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/ibm-mq/info) for a link to the download.